# Make specific URLs use a template file and get specific data from array with PHP and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

**Goal:**

I want to create an array of products which is used to populate individual product pages via a singular template file and the URL to be `/products/product-name`.

---

**What I currently have:**

A file structure like this:

- index.php
- products/product-a.php
- products/product-b.php
- products/product-c.php

This is cumbersome as it means adding a product file each time I have a new product and the markup could then become inconsistent between the files over time.

---

I also have a root `.htaccess` file like this to make the URLs lose the .php and add a trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Disable directory indexing

Options -Indexes

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

---

The `.htaccess` makes the `domain.com/products/product-a.php` resolve at `domain.com/products/product-a/`

Instead of creating individual files for products (`product-a.php`, `product-b.php`, etc) I instead want to put the data for each product in an array like this:

```
function products() {
    $products = array();
    $products[a] = array(
        'heading' => 'Product A',
        'content' => '<p>Some text</p>',
    );
    $products[b] = array(
        'heading' => 'Product B',
        'content' => '<p>Some text</p>',
    );
    return $products;
}
```

And then have a single template file called `product.php`, if the URL is `/products/[any-product-title]/` it will keep the URL but use the template file which will get the data from the array like this:

```
<?php
$products = products();
$product = $products[a]; // Unsure on how to make this dynamically select the correct product
?>
<h1><?php echo $product['heading']; ?></h1>
<?php echo $product['content']; ?>
```

**Where I am struggling:**

I do not know how to make it so that when a product URL is resolved it will use the template file and then after this how to get the template file to use the correct product from the array, I assume this could be done by giving the product array key the URL somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a routing system, provided by any framework.

If you are working without framework, you can manage it with this kind of simple approach.

Be sure you have these conditions in your *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Then, in your *index.php* (or somewhere else, depending on your structure, includes,...) declare your products:

```
// Here is your products data
$productsList = [
    "a" => [
        'heading' => 'Product A',
        'content' => '<p>Some text</p>'
    ],
    "b" => [
        'heading' => 'Product B',
        'content' => '<p>Some text</p>'
    ]
];
```

And this simple code will load the product information in a single "template":

```
// This is the common URI to reach your products
$routePrefix = "/products/product-";

// This is the product key from URI
$productToDisplay = str_replace($routePrefix, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// Display product data
if (array_key_exists($productToDisplay, $productsList)) {
    print_r($productsList[$productToDisplay]);
} else {
    echo "Sorry, we did not find this product.";
}
```

Of course, it has to be improved with your specific needs. Also, keep in mind the security issues you can face. A routing system from a framework is better.

*EDIT: note that you don't need a '/product' folder anymore and that there is no connection between your folders structure and the used URI. In this example, the common URI could be '/products-and-services/products/free-products/.../product-' and it will work.*